# Why does this return 'never' type?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I found something really interesting.

```
type q = number & string;
```

As you can see, on hovering over `q`, I see it is of type `'never'`. Why is this so?

Comment: Because there is no value that would satisfy this type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is that `never` means that the variable will never happen/occur, so when you declare a variable to be an intersection (&) of both `number` and `string`, TypeScript will try to find types that are both `number` and `string` at the same time...

Which will **never** happen, as the two types do not intersect. I guess an equivalent analog is that you are trying to find something that is both a left hand and a right hand, which will never happen.

Comment: That's interesting. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

A value can never be of type `number` *and* `string`. Hence, its type is `never`.